# Symfony Serializer Deserializing XML into Object with children

Tags: php, serialization, symfony4

I have the following XML:

```
<CinemaListExport>
    <Cinema>
        ....
        <screens>
            <screen></screen>
            <screen></screen>
        </screens>
    </Cinema>
    <Cinema>
    ....
    </Cinema>
<CinemaListExport>
```

I am trying to convert this into the following objects:

```
class CinemaList
{
    /**
     * @var Cinema[]
     */
    public $cinema;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cinema = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addCinema(Cinema $cinema)
    {
        $this->cinema[] = $cinema;
    }
```

```
class Cinema
{
    fields...

    /**
     * @var Screen[]
     */
    public $screens = [];
```

with the following code:

```
        $normalizers = [
            new ArrayDenormalizer(),
            new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor())
        ];
        $encoders = [new XmlEncoder()];

        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);


        $res = $serializer->deserialize($xml, CinemaList::class, 'xml');
```

No matter what I do I always get the following:

```
class CinemaList#265 (1) {
  public $cinema =>
  class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection#317 (1) {
    private $elements =>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong here? 
I just need CinemaList to contain all the Cinemas and each Cinema to contain all it's screens

Answer (score 2):

Well i had to develop your solution and made some search to understand why this simply use case doesn't work.

First you miss the normalizer `ArrayDenormalizer` it's required to unserialize your collections of cinema and screen:

```php
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\ReflectionExtractor;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

$objectNormalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor());

$serializer = new Serializer(
    [new ArrayDenormalizer(), $objectNormalizer], [new XmlEncoder()]
);
```

Without this normalizer array and collection are just skipped.

There is another thing about serializing/unserializing and in particular with the `ObjectNormalizer` which use `PropertyAccess` component.

You have to implement both method `adder` and `remover` if you want to make it works.

> A lot of things happens in the PropertyAccessor::writeProperty methods. I won’t explain all the mecanism, but shortly: if you have methods addXXX and removeXXX, then addXXX will be used in priority. Take care ! if you only have the addXXX method, then it won’t be used… I don’t know why they did this but there is certainly a good reason. 
>   The second options is the setter. If it exists (and you don’t have removeXXX or addXXX), then it will be used to add the items from the collections.

from [here](https://medium.com/@rebolon/the-symfony-serializer-a-great-but-complex-component-fbc09baa65a0)

I did some successfull test in a new symfony project. If you still run into issues i'll be glad to help you.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am reviewing the links and will try it out.
Not sure why this Serializer needs to be so complicated...